# iOS Core data - problem saving new value to existing objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm trying to save new value for an existing core data object:

```
[object setValue:Value forKey:NotificationKey];
NSError *error;
[object.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

It's not saving the new data. Without any warning but maybe there is a problem with the `save` method. The process is going on background and invoking local notification at the end. After trying to find what's wrong, I've tried to make the `save` method before invoking the notification and it didn't rise.

Anyone sees the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Need more code... Do you get any warnings, crash logs, etc?

Comment: change `[object.managedObjectContext save:&error]` to `if([object.managedObjectContext save:&error] { NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]); abort(); }`. If app crashes, there is a CoreData error somewhere. Does it crash?

Comment: Yeap, `Unresolved error (null), (null)`, what's it might be?

Comment: @Kashiv -- your if-statement needs to be `if (![object.manag....` because the method returns YES if it succeeds and NO otherwise. The statement now will return every time the save succeeds and then try to print the value of the nil error object which produces the `(null)`

Comment: How do you know the changes are not being saved?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try again. I know because the next time it runs, notification is invoked only if the value doesn't exists. And it's being invoked a lot. Any other problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the save occurs on a background thread/operation, you must merge the foreground and background threads/operations before changes made in one are available to the other.

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing that, the problem is that the object isn't being saved and the next time I'm getting the same notifications (I'm trying to saved the data to flag that a notification already invoked and doesn't need anymore)

Comment: You mean the notifications sent by the NSManagedObjectContext or something else? I'm not clear at all what your setup is or what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to save notifications in Core Data. Instead, you should save a flag in the user defaults. Core Data is for user data while user defaults are for application state information.